# Executing PHP in files folder, Nginx

Tags: nginx, php

I have a Joomla installed and need to allow users run one PHP file from /media folder.
How to do it?

With current config, Nginx returnes this PHP as file for download, without executing it.
Here is a part of my config:

```
location ~* /media {
   allow all;
   expires      1d;
}

location /media/dir/test.php {
   fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
   #PHP here works fine
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   # .. skipped ...
}
```

Comment: Is your fastcgi configured properly? Try `location = /media/dir/test.php { }`

Comment: As I have said, PHP executing in / is OK. And location you have told I already added (see config).
Adding "=" does not affect anything.

Comment: where's your php block that executes `/` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have understood where the problem is.
I was need in swap "location ~* /media" block with "location /media/dir/test.php" blocks in the file to have right priority.